# Dependants fields inside collectionType

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

### What I Have ...

Got an OperationForm containing a collection of PaymentEmbeddedForm.

### What I intend to do

I want to add some dependant fields in my entries inside the collection of PaymentEmbeddedForm.

### The wall i'm hitting.

If some fields are dynamically added inside one of my PaymentEmbeddedForm then when the OperationForm (the root form) is submited, it doesn't recognize the new data, only the field from which the other dependants fields are bound.

#### Example

- OperationFrom

  - field1
  - field2
  - field3 : (Collection of PaymentEmbeddedForm)
  - Payment1 (PaymentEmbeddedForm)

    - Payment1.field1
    - Payment1.field2
    - **Payment1.field3 (dynamically added)**
  - Payment2 (PaymentEmbeddedForm)

    - Payment2.field1
    - Payment2.field2

In this case, the data of Payment1.field3 will not be bound at my form ....

### What I've tried

#### Events manipulation inside PaymentEmbeddedForm

If I create an independant PaymentEmbeddedForm, there is no problème, the dependants fields are well bound at my form.

#### Events manipulation inside OperationForm

When I debug the data of the form with *dump($data)*, I can't see the data of the dependants fields. They are always null at first submition. But once the form has been submitted at least once, the following submition is OK, the data is well bound.

### My code

```php
//****************************************
//PaymentEmbeddedForm.php
//****************************************

class PaymentEmbeddedForm extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var AccountRepository  $accountRepo*/
    private $accountRepo;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /** @var Organization $org */
        $org = $options['organization'];

        $builder
            ->add('method', EntityType::class, [
                'placeholder' => '-- Choississez un moyen de paiement --',
                'class' => PaymentMethod::class,
                'choice_label' => 'displayName',
                'choice_value' => 'name'
            ])
        ;

        $builder
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use ($org) {
                return $this->onPreSetData($event, $org);
            })
            ->get('method')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) use ($org) {
                return $this->methodOnPostSubmit($event, $org);
            })
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Payment::class,
            'organization' => false
        ]);

        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('organization', 'App\Entity\Core\Organization');

    }

    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event, Organization $org)
    {
        /** @var Payment $payment */
        $payment = $event->getData();

        if (!$payment)
            return;

        $this->setupSpecificMethodFields($event->getForm(), $payment->getMethod(), $org);
        return;

    }
    public function methodOnPostSubmit(FormEvent $event, ?Organization $org)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $this->setupSpecificMethodFields(
            $form->getParent(),
            $form->getData(),
            $org
        );
    }

    private function setupSpecificMethodFields(FormInterface $form, ?PaymentMethod $method, ?Organization $org)
    {

//        $form
//            ->remove('account')
//            ->remove('amount')
//            ->remove('iban')
//            ->remove('number')
//            ->remove('paidAt')
//            ->remove('isPaid')
//        ;

        if (null === $method) {
            return;
        }

        $this->setupAmountField($form);
        $this->setupPaidAtField($form);
        $this->setupIsPaidField($form);

        if (in_array($method->getName(), ['cash', 'credit_card', 'check', 'transfer', 'direct_debit', 'direct_debit_in_installments', 'interbank_payment_order']))
            $this->setupAccountField($form, $method, $org);
        if (in_array($method->getName(), ['check', 'voucher']))
            $this->setupNumberField($form);
        if (in_array($method->getName(), ['direct_debit', 'direct_debit_in_installments']))
            $this->setupIbanField($form);

    }

    private function setupPaidAtField(FormInterface $form): void
    {
        $form->add('paidAt', DateType::class);
        return;
    }
    private function setupIsPaidField(FormInterface $form): void
    {
        $form->add('isPaid');
        return;
    }
    private function setupAccountField(FormInterface $form, PaymentMethod $method, Organization $org): void
    {

        $accountChoices = new ArrayCollection();

        switch($method->getName()) {
            case 'cash':
                $accountChoices = $org->getBankAccounts();
                break;
            case 'credit_card':
            case 'check':
            case 'transfer':
            case 'direct_debit':
            case 'direct_debit_in_installments':
            case 'interbank_payment_order':
                $accountChoices = $org->getBankAccounts();
                break;
        }

        $form->add('account', AccountType::class, [
            'choices' => $accountChoices
        ]);
    }
    private function setupAmountField(FormInterface $form): void
    {
        $form->add('amount', MoneyType::class);
        return;
    }
    private function setupIbanField(FormInterface $form): void
    {
        $form->add('iban');
    }
    private function setupNumberField(FormInterface $form): void
    {
        $form->add('number');
    }
}
```

```php
//****************************************
// OperationFormType.php
//****************************************


class OperationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var AccountRepository  $accountRepo*/
    private $accountRepo;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->accountRepo = $em->getRepository(Account::class);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('amount', MoneyType::class)
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('account', AccountType::class, [
                'choices' => $this->accountRepo->getChildren($this->accountRepo->findOneBy([
                    'code' => $options['type'] == 'income' ? 7 : 6,
                    'chart' => $options['organization']->getChart()->getId()
                ]), false, null, 'ASC', false)
            ])
            ->add('operateAt', DateType::class)
            ->add('payments', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_options' => [
                    'organization' => $options['organization']
                ],
                'entry_type' => PaymentEmbeddedForm::class,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true
            ])

            ->add('reset', ResetType::class, [
                'label' => 'Réinitialiser'
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Enregistrer'
            ])
        ;

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));

        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => OperationFormModel::class,
            'organization' => false,
            'type' => null
        ]);

        $resolver
            ->setAllowedTypes('organization', 'App\Entity\Core\Organization')
            ->setAllowedTypes('type', ['string', 'null'])
            ->setAllowedValues('type', ['expense', 'income', null])
        ;
    }

    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var OperationFormModel $data */
        $data = $event->getData();

        if ($data->getPayments()->isEmpty()) {
            $newPayment = new Payment();
            $newPayment->setPaidAt(new DateTime());
            $data->addPayment($newPayment);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for you're help.

Bdisklaz

Comment: afaict your approach seems sensible, there are just some events missing. please (re)read exactly, what each event means and when it is triggered. I believe you need at least one of pre_submit or submit as well, removing unfitting fields in the process (as your commented out code suggests). post_submit is definitely the wrong time to add/remove form fields.

Comment: Hi @Jakumi, thanks for your answer.

I've tried every possible combinations (but the good one :) )playing with `FormEvent` inside both my `OperationFormType` and my `PaymentEmbeddedForm`. I'm kind of lost...

The reason I implement the `setupSpecificMethodField()` inside the `FormEvent::POST_SUBMIT` event is for the form to detect the new fields automatically and map them to the submitted client data (as it's explained in the official symfony doc [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms)).